# Multi match and highlighting in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight

When I try to match one field in query everything works fine with [highlighting in elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html).

When I try to use:

```
$params = [
'index' => 'my_index',
'type' => 'articles',
'body' => [
    'from' => '0',
    'size' => '10',
    'query' => [
        'bool' => [
            'must' => [
                'match' => [ 'content' => 'what I want to search' ]
                ]
            ]
    ],
    'highlight' => [
        'pre_tags' => ['<mark>'],
        'post_tags' => ['</mark>'],
        'fields' => [
            'content' => [ 'fragment_size' => 150, 'number_of_fragments' => 3 ]
        ]
    ],
]
```

];

everything works, but when I try to catch multiple fields, my search works correctly, but highlighting disappears.

```
'match' => [ 'content' => 'what I want to search' ],
'match' => [ 'type' => 1 ]
```

Do you know how to achieve functional highlighting, when I want apply search on two different fields with two different queries?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'articles',
    'body' => [
        'from' => '0',
        'size' => '10',
        'query' => [
          'bool' => [
            'must' => [
                'match' => [ 'content' => 'what I want to search' ]
                ]
            ],
                'filter' => ['type' => 1]
         ]
            ]    ],
    'highlight' => [
        'pre_tags' => ['<mark>'],
        'post_tags' => ['</mark>'],
        'fields' => [
            'content' => [ 'fragment_size' => 150, 'number_of_fragments' => 3 ]
        ]
    ],
]
```